# Cannot resolve method 'addOnTabSelectedListener(anonymous android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener)'

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

I don't know why but I'm not able to use `addOnTabSelectedListener`, though I'm able to use `setOnTabSelectedListener()` but I don't want to. Here is my code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);
    int width = size.x;

    drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    back = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.back_navigation);
    fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab_explore);
    viewPager = (CustomViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager_home);
    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation2);
    navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);

    DrawerLayout.LayoutParams params = (DrawerLayout.LayoutParams) navigationView.getLayoutParams();
    params.width = (int) (width * 0.9);
    navigationView.setLayoutParams(params);

    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            drawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        }
    });
    setupViewPager(viewPager);
    back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        }
    });
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    setupIcon();
    tabLayout.getTabAt(0).getIcon().setAlpha(255);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(1).getIcon().setAlpha(100);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(2).getIcon().setAlpha(100);
    tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });
}

public void setupIcon() {
    tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(tabIcons[0]);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(tabIcons[1]);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setIcon(tabIcons[2]);
}

private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(new Digest(), "Digest");
    adapter.addFragment(new Topics(), "Topics");
    adapter.addFragment(new Profile(), "Profile");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. My compileSdkVersion is 23 and all android support libraries are 23 as well.

Comment: The `addOnTabSelectedListener()` method wasn't added until version 24.0.0. You need to upgrade your library version if you want to use it, or roll it yourself.

Comment: @MikeM. yup working now, thanks man!

Answer (score 1):

Add dependencies inside your build.gradle file

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
}
```

Comment: Not working bro. I'm currently using 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your build version and design support library versions are same. In your case build tool version and your design support library versions are different, So your are facing that problem

for example in my case:

```
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'
```

and in dependencies

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
```

and that error will be gone for sure.